# Bootstrap centre div when a row is not full

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have videos being displayed via ng-repeat. I need the video itself to sit flush with the body card (We are following material design) and for *"reasons"* I am not allowed to use a dynamic video width.

So what I have had to do is attach the bootstrap class to a transparent parent div on the video like so

```
<div class="col-md-4 etc etc">
 <div class="videoWithFixedHeight">
```

This works great and stacks the video cards depending on screen size as it should. However, when there is only one/two/three videos I would like them to auto centre (text-align: centre **does not work**). The problem here is that I somehow need bootstrap to know how many videos there are and align them accordingly..

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could add .col-md-offset-2 as explained here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 etc etc">
```

Comment: I did give this a try earlier, It does work but when there is more than one video it will put each video on their own row and not in-line :(

Answer (score 0):

Use "justify-content-center" class from bootstrap.
Add to a div, like so:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
```

This will center columns of bootstrap.